# Alternative for "for loop" for checking corresponding ID's

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have a `products array` - an array containing objects of a range of products - and I have an `subscriptionItems array` - which contains all the items a user adds to their shopping cart. Both arrays use useState.

My function `addItem` takes an object from the `products array`, and adds it to the `subscriptionItems array`. However, if the added product is already in the `subscriptionItems array`, the item won't be added again, but the amount of the product object will be increased, based on the second if statement.

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState(data);
const [subscriptionItems, setSubscriptionItems] = useState(initialSubscriptionProducts)

const addItem = (itemId) => {
    let len = products.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (products[i].id === itemId) {
        let lenSub = subscriptionItems.length;
        for (let j = 0; j < lenSub; j++) {
          if (subscriptionItems[j].id === itemId) {
            setSubscriptionItems(
              (subscriptionItems[j].amount = subscriptionItems[j].amount + 1)
            );
          } else {
            setSubscriptionItems((prevArray) => [...prevArray, products[i]]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

The problem is that the product will be added as often as the for loop is completed, which is never when the initial `subscriptionItems` array is empty. I only want to add or increase the product once, but I really don't know an alternative way to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put your Subscriptions logic in a separate function.  I think you'll find that will make the logic much easier to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this. Create a helper function that will tell whether a given product is in the `subscriptionItems` array, and return you its index if it is there.

```
const productIndex = (itemID) => {
   for (let i = 0; i < subscriptionItems.length; i++) {
      if (subscriptionItems[i].id === itemID) {
         return i;
      }
   }
   return null;
}
```

Another helper function will get you product by its ID:

```
const getProductByID = (itemID) => {
   for (let i = 0; i <= products.length; i ++) {
      if (product.id === itemID) {
         return product;
      }
   }
}
```

Then use these functions in `addItem`. Note that you don't really need the product unless you want to insert it to the array, thus we will load it only if it's not present in the subscriptionsItems.

```
const addItem = (itemID) => {
   const index = productIndex(itemID);
   if (index) {
      setSubscriptionItems(
         (subscriptionItems[index].amount = subscriptionItems[index].amount + 1)
      );
   } else {
      const product = getProductByID(itemID);
      setSubscriptionItems((prevArray) => [...prevArray, product]);
   }
}
```

Now the logic is separated and the code is not repeated unnecessarily.

Comment: Now I see what Robert Harvey meant, this code is much cleaner, thanks for the insight. However, I get an error when running through ProductIndex function though, it says "undefined is not an object, evaluating subscriptionItems[i].id",  I guess this happens when looping through an empty array. I added "if (subscriptionItems[i] != undefined) {...}" in the second line of the Product Index function, but when a product is added in the subscriptionItems array, it adds "undefined" as an array item.

Comment: You may have a problem with how `products` and `subscriptionItems` are initialised in the first place. If `subscriptionItems` are initialised as `[]`, there is no way `productIndex` will throw such an error. Try to use some `console.log`s to see where the problem can be.